# Hash - nested traversal - Ruby - (Any one know this)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I have this hash

```
hasha = {"a" => "b","a_a" => {"x_y" => "sreeraj","a_b" => "hereIam"}}
```

I need to change this to

```
hasha = {"a" => "b","a-a" => {"x-y" => "sreeraj","a-b" => "hereIam"}}
```

i.e. I need to change all keys containing `"_"`(underscore) to `"-"`(minus). How can I do this?

Comment: Is it possible there will be arrays of hashes, or is it pure nested hashes?

Comment: This is not a question. Please show us what you have tried so far

Comment: @lucapette "This is not a question. Please show us what you have tried so far " . May i know what is not clear in my question?

Comment: @Mark, sorry Mark I need a pure Hash :(

Comment: @Sreeraj I don't what to be rude but my "this is not a question" is related to this: http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is might not be the smarter one, but it works:

```
def rep_key(hash={})  
    newhash={}
    hash.each_pair do |key,val|
        val = rep_key(val) if val.class == Hash
        newhash[key.sub(/_/,'-')] = val
    end
    newhash
end
```

where:

```
hasha = {"a" => "b","a_a" => {"x_y" => "sreeraj","a_b" => "hereIam"}}
newhash = rep_key hasha
puts newhash.inspect
```

gives:

```
newhash = {"a" => "b","a-a" => {"x-y" => "sreeraj","a-b" => "hereIam"}}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try recursion.

```
def replace_all(x, a, b)
    return if x.class != Hash
    y = Hash.new
    x.each do |k,v|
        if(v.class == Hash)
            v = replace_all(v, a, b)
        end

        if k.class == String and k.include?(a)
            y[k.gsub(a,b)] = v
        else
            y[k] = v
        end
    end
    return y
end

hasha = {"a" => "b","a_a" => {"x_y" => "sreeraj","a_b" => "hereIam"}}

puts replace_all(hasha, "_", "-")
```